# Use nested stored procedure results in calling stored procedure Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is it possible to use the results of one stored procedure in another stored procedure?

I.e.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc1]
        @ID INT,
        @mfgID INT,
        @DealerID INT

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Proc1Result UserDefinedTableVariable

    EXEC @Proc1Result = Proc2
        @SomeID = @ID,
        @SomeID2 = @mfgID,
        @SomeID3 = @DealerID

    -- Now I want to use the table returned by the stored procedure here.
    SELECT [col1],[col2] FROM @Proc1Result

END
```

I tried using `INSERT INTO @Proc1Result EXEC Proc2 (with parameters passed)`, but `INSERT EXEC` cannot be called in a nested statement.

Is there any way of accomplishing this? The environment is SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can nest stored procedures [up to 32 levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190607.aspx).

I would recommend reading over [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC) regarding INSERT-EXEC.  Here is a snippit:

> If some_sp tries to call some_other_sp
>   with INSERT-EXEC, you will get an
>   error message. Thus, you can only have
>   one INSERT-EXEC active at a time. This
>   is a restriction in SQL Server.

Answer (score 5):

You're right, `INSERT ... EXEC` cannot nest. From [How to Share Data Between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC).

> It can't nest. If `some_sp` tries to
>   call `some_other_sp` with INSERT-EXEC,
>   you will get an error message. Thus,
>   you can only have one INSERT-EXEC
>   active at a time. This is a
>   restriction in SQL Server.

You need to find some other way. Erland's article linked goes trough pretty much all the options you have and discusses them at great detail.

Comment: How is it that I posted the exact same link and quote 2 minutes before you but you have more up votes?  Must be the teddy bear...

Comment: @Abe: mine has formatted the procedure names, that takes hours and hours of work and voters appreciate the extra effort ;)

Comment: Remus also quotes a larger portion from the source, which must undoubtedly provide the OP with more context on the topic. :)

Answer (score 2):

One syntax for getting results into one sp from another is:

```
INSERT INTO [myTable]
EXEC Proc1 [param1], [param2], [param3], etc.
```

But you have to create the table first that it inserts into and the field names and types have to exactly match.

Comment: The other two answers aren't even consistent. (You can nest them by the way.) I don't really see where the OP states that he's nesting them more than once, but maybe I'm not understanding correctly.