# Call stored procedure in another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to get the result of gpa multiplies credit of a course by score:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GpaCreditFromScore
(
    @score INT,
    @credits INT, 
    @gpaCredit INT OUTPUT
)
AS 
IF (@score < 60)
BEGIN
    SET @gpaCredit = 0.0
END
ELSE IF (@score < 62)
BEGIN
    SET @gpaCredit = 1.0 * @credits
END
ELSE IF (@score < 65)
BEGIN
    SET @gpaCredit = 1.7 * @credits
END
ELSE IF (@score < 67)
BEGIN
    SET @gpaCredit = 2.0 * @credits
END
ELSE IF (@score < 70)
BEGIN
    SET @gpaCredit = 2.3 * @credits
END
ELSE IF (@score < 75)
BEGIN
    SET @gpaCredit = 2.7 * @credits
END
ELSE IF (@score < 80)
BEGIN
    SET @gpaCredit = 3.0 * @credits
END
ELSE IF (@score < 85)
BEGIN
    SET @gpaCredit = 3.3 * @credits
END
ELSE IF (@score < 90)
BEGIN
    SET @gpaCredit = 3.7 * @credits
END
ELSE IF (@score < 95)
BEGIN
    SET @gpaCredit = 4.0 * @credits
END
ELSE IF (@score <= 100)
BEGIN
    SET @gpaCredit = 4.3 * @credits
END
```

And another stored procedure to calculate all students' gpa multiplies credit:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ComputeGpa
AS
    ;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT StudentID, Score, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (PARTITION BY StudentID, CourseID 
    ORDER BY Semester DESC) 
  FROM dbo.UndergraduateScoreSet
)
SELECT StudentID, Gpa /* call dbo.GpaCreditFromScore here to get @gpaCredit */
FROM x
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY StudentID;
```

Since the logic is quite complex, I don't know how to achieve this. Please help~

Comment: If you had a table with columns `LowerScoreBound`, `UpperScoreBound` and `Multiplier`, you could easily obtain the multiplier as a set based operation. You could then drastically simplify your stored proc (which ought to be a UDF really) or eliminate it entirely.

Comment: Rather than editing your question to include the answer, you should post the answer as... an answer (then please rollback your edit also).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, because the proc dbo.GpaCreditFromScore takes and returns scalar parameters, it would mean that you have to iterate through your students to compute all scores, by using something horrid like a cursor.

As @Damien mentions, you should change `dbo.GpaCreditFromScore` to be a user defined function like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GpaCreditFromScore
(
    @score INT,
    @credits INT 
)
RETURNS INT 
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @gpaCredit INT
        IF (@score < 60)
        BEGIN
            SET @gpaCredit = 0.0
        END
        ELSE IF (@score < 62)
        BEGIN
            SET @gpaCredit = 1.0 * @credits
        END
        ELSE IF (@score < 65)
        BEGIN
            SET @gpaCredit = 1.7 * @credits
        END
        ELSE IF (@score < 67)
        BEGIN
            SET @gpaCredit = 2.0 * @credits
        END
        ELSE IF (@score < 70)
        BEGIN
            SET @gpaCredit = 2.3 * @credits
        END
        ELSE IF (@score < 75)
        BEGIN
            SET @gpaCredit = 2.7 * @credits
        END
        ELSE IF (@score < 80)
        BEGIN
            SET @gpaCredit = 3.0 * @credits
        END
        ELSE IF (@score < 85)
        BEGIN
            SET @gpaCredit = 3.3 * @credits
        END
        ELSE IF (@score < 90)
        BEGIN
            SET @gpaCredit = 3.7 * @credits
        END
        ELSE IF (@score < 95)
        BEGIN
            SET @gpaCredit = 4.0 * @credits
        END
        ELSE IF (@score <= 100)
        BEGIN
            SET @gpaCredit = 4.3 * @credits
        END
        RETURN @gpaCredit
    END
```

Your Stored Proc doesn't quite work (Where does Credits come from?), but the idea is now to use the UDF on your CTE's fields, like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ComputeGpa
AS
    ;WITH x AS 
    (
      SELECT StudentID, Score, 9 AS Credits, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
       (PARTITION BY StudentID, CourseID 
        ORDER BY Semester DESC) 
      FROM dbo.UndergraduateScoreSet
    )
    SELECT StudentID, dbo.GpaCreditFromScore(Score, Credits) AS GpaCredit
    FROM x
    WHERE rn = 1
    GROUP BY StudentID;
```

**EDIT** OP spotted a bug - because of the GROUP BY, we need an aggregate, of course. Thanks!:

```
    SELECT StudentID, SUM(dbo.GpaCreditFromScore(Score, Credits)) AS GpaCredit
```

Comment: It works as I mentioned in the end of the question. But your answer really helped a lot! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to you

[Use nested stored procedure results in calling stored procedure Sql Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880627/use-nested-stored-procedure-results-in-calling-stored-procedure-sql-server-2008)

You can use in this way

```
IF .....
INSERT #Tbl (Fields)
EXEC usp_SelectProc1 @Arg1, Arg2...Argn
ELSE
INSERT #Tbl (Fields)
EXEC usp_SelectProc2 @Arg1, Arg2...Argn
```